# How to add Horizontal Scrolling to a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview

I am working on to use a Horizontal scrolling in a particular `UIView`. Here, I am created the one scroll view then I add the `UIView`. This `UIView` is sub view of `UIScrollView`. The `UIView` contains the UIElements Like labels, Images..etc. For scrolling functionality I add the page control.

"I need to implement the horizontal scrolling to this `UIView` (left/right Scrolling)."

I don't know how to do this.Can any one help me for this functionality. Here I am attaching the my page screen shot.

[image]

In this image contains the `UIScrollView` and `UIView`. The bordered view is UIView. Then background view is scroll view. I want to scroll this bordered `UIView`.

Here is my code:

```
 //This is my Horizontal scrolling code:

 for(int i = 0;i < self.catagoriesAPI_Array.count;i++)
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = self.view.frame.size.width * i;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.view.frame.size;

    self.favoriteSub_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    favoriteModelOB = [self.catagoriesAPI_Array objectAtIndex:i];

    self.itemFavoriteName_LB.text = favoriteModelOB.rewards_program_description;

    [_favorites_scroll_view addSubview:_favoriteSub_view];  // add the subview for scroll view
}
_offers_Scroll_view.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width * [self.catagoriesAPI_Array count], _offers_Scroll_view.frame.size.height);
```

//Scroll view Delegates:

```
  -(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
      {
        CGFloat pageWidth = _offers_Scroll_view.frame.size.width;
          int page = floor((_offers_Scroll_view.contentOffset.x - pageWidth / 2) / pageWidth) + 1;
_pageControl.currentPage = page;

CGFloat pageWidth1 = _favorites_scroll_view.frame.size.width;
int page1 = floor((_favorites_scroll_view.contentOffset.x - pageWidth1 / 2) / pageWidth1) + 1;
_pageControl.currentPage = page1;
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `UIView` inside the `UIScrollView`.
Active the horizontal scrolling in the `UIScrollView` properties and finally define a bigger `UIScrollView.contentSize` than the `UIScrollView.frame` size width.
If done like this, you'll be able to scroll the UIScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

// give maximumu width for your View as per you requirement and give the contentsize for scrollview as like as follows

```
scrollview.contentSize = view.frame.size
```